# How and where is a yellow accessibility focus box drawn in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am looking for source code in android where it draws the yellow accessibility focus box. After going through View.java source code in Android I can see that whenever a view is touched in accessibility mode, its requestAccessibilityFocus() method is called which further calls invalidate() on the view. But I am interested to know how does the view draws yellow rectangle around it. SInce nowhere in stack trace is this rectangle defined nor does the invalidate method seem to take into account if the view is accessiblityfocused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow accessibility box is drawn in ViewRootImp.drawAccessibilityFocusDrawableIfNeeded()